# Why my test of video element time control in html5 doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, dom-events

```
var v = document.getElementsByTagNames('video')

var dispay_timeboard = function() { if(v.currentTime.toPrecision(5) == '22.866') {time_board.style.display='block'}}
```

//the time code in srt file is 00:00:22,866 so I convert it to '22.866'

```
v.addEventListener('timeupdate',display_timeboard,false)
```

I works, but it shows just a second after I hit play button, what's mistake I made, and is there a more mature frame work to handle this besides popcorn.js(I'm le)

Answer (score 0):

it don t really got your problem, but checking for exact time with "==" might not be the best way, because your timeupdate isn't fired in specific intervals.

this means your comparing fails if timeupdate fires f.e. 22.850 and 22.900. try using sth like this:

```
var dispay_timeboard = function() { 
   var currentTime = v.currentTime.toPrecision(5);
   if( currentTime  > '22.800' || currentTime < '22.900') 
      {time_board.style.display='block'}
}
```

and i prefer mootools as a javascript framework. jquery is a good one too